# Calendar control for ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have managed to find several ionic calendar modules but cannot find any **calendar control**  modules where a user can select from available dates. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-custom-formly-template-using-datepicker-plugin

I have used the `$cordovaDatePicker` plugin successfully here and integrated it with formly in this blog post with a full working project.

here is the plugin - http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDatePicker) {

  var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date', // or 'time'
    minDate: new Date() - 10000,
    allowOldDates: true,
    allowFutureDates: false,
    doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
    doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
    cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
        alert(date);
    });

  }, false);
});
```